# How can I cross-browser detect input fields with the 'required' attribute in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, forms, html, attributes, required

I am running into a slight validation issue with the Boolean `required` attribute on form fields.

I am marking up my fields as such:

```
<label for="email">Email Address:</label>
<input value="" type="email" name="email" id="email" required />
```

But trying to find all required fields using jQuery and adding them to an array seems problematic due to detection issues.

The following only works in Firefox (Gecko) `$(':input[required=""]')` but returns nothing in Webkit (Safari, Chrome).

Webkit on the other hand return all required fields if I run `$(':input[required]')` or `$(':input[required="true"]')`, but when this runs through Gecko it doesn't return the required fields.

What am I doing wrong here? Last I checked the input attribute was simply `required` and neither `required="required"` nor `required="true"`.

Is there a better way of detecting all the required fields using javascript/jQuery?

Comment: Required is not a valid attribute. Any reason why you aren't using something like `class="required"` instead? Then grabbing the elements with jQuery would be trivial: `jQuery('input.required')`

Comment: required IS a valid HTML5 attribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be a bad workaround, but have your tried a multiple selector?

```
$(':input[required=""],:input[required]')
```

Comment: Yup, that's what I am currently doing as a work around, i just thought that there would be a better way for this to be done :) Thanks though.

Comment: @Jannis :input alone is a performance killer, this will search every element in the dom to find input fields.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go. This will output an array with all required fields.

```
<input value="" type="email" name="email" id="email" required/>
<input value="" type="email" name="email1" id="email1"  required/>
<input value="" type="email" name="email2" id="email2"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
var x = $('input[required]').get();
console.log(x); // x will contain an array of required inputs [input#email, input#email1]
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I can confirm this as working, though ideally I would like to continue using the `:input` selector so that not just `input` are detected but also `textarea` for instance. Can that also be done or will I need to check for textareas as a second selector `$('input[required],textarea[required]').get();` ?

Comment: @jannis Yes certainly you can do that, separate elements by comma. another way you can so this is assign a common class for all fields you want to include, and just reference the element by class name ex: $('.class[required]')

Comment: Thanks for the update, great way to find these fields though personally I prefer not having class names as such hooks, but that's just me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

with bootstrap 3, you can do:

```
$('input[required]')
    .closest(".form-group")
    .children("label")
    .append(" <i class='fa fa-asterisk'></i>");
```